# CSV to JSON with primary key to Firebase

Tags: python, json, pandas, firebase, csv

I am trying to save a CSV to the database on Firebase, but the problem is that I have thousands of this:

```
Nro;Apellido;Nombre;Celular
     1;Manchini;Mariela Gladis;+54 349 652 520 2 
     2;Salinas ;Eliana ;+54 113 235 878 1
```

and I need something like this:

```
"1": {
            "Apellido": "Manchini",
            "Celular": "+54 349 652 520 2",
            "Nombre": "Elianas"
          },
          "2": {
            "Apellido": "Salinas ",
            "Celular": "+54 113 235 878 1 ",
            "Nombre": Eliana "
          }
    }
```

I tried but the result is not the one that I want, Please help I am new to this:

```
my_df = pd.read_csv('NewYork-03-19-0.csv')

 my_json = dict(my_df.set_index('Nro').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 
 x.to_json(orient='records')))

 with open('my_json.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_json, outfile)


{"1": "[{\"Apellido\":\"Torres\",\"Nombre\":\"Loredana \",\"Celular\":\" 91 451 039 07 \"}]", 
  "2": "[{\"Apellido\":\"Nu\\u00f1ez\",\"Nombre\":\"Patricia\",\"Celular\":\"134 766 662 48 \"}]"
```

I tried many pieces of different codes and even tried to create something but I didn't have good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
my_df = pd.read_csv('NewYork-03-19-0.csv', sep=";")
```

Comment: with open(dir,encoding = 'utf-8') as csvFile:
        csvReader= csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for csvRow in csvReader:
            nro=csvRow['Nro']
            data[nro]=csvRow